# Angular2 Material2 bind to onMenuClose

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to detect when the menu closes to unset a value, I have been using close that looks like this.

```
<md-menu #dataActions="mdMenu"  (onMenuClose)="alert('a')">
    <button md-menu-item (click)="doEdit()" *ngIf="!isLocked()">
        <md-icon>edit</md-icon>
        <span>Edit</span>
    </button>
    <button md-menu-item (click)="doSubmit()" *ngIf="isEdit()">
        <md-icon>done</md-icon>
        <span>Submit</span>
    </button>
</md-menu>
```

I can tell i am binding to something that exists because it does not throw an error ... however when the close events run it never registers to the actual event.  Does anyone have any ideas? or is this a bug in material?

Comment: Maybe try using a function in your typescript file instead of using `alert()`? Like `doSomething: void {alert('a')}`

Comment: I originally started with a ts function and it was not being called.  So i tried alert then come to post this.  But are you able to confirm that i am doing it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

There were a few minor issues, the onMenuClose event is fired at the same level as the mdMenuTriggerFor ... therefore the bind needed to be on the calling item not the menu itself.  Also as @Edric stated, it had to be a typescript function and not a generic alert.  Here is another code snipit that works:

```
<md-icon [mdMenuTriggerFor]="dataActions" (onMenuOpen)="actionMenuOpen(row)" (onMenuClose)="actionMenuClose()" fxFill fxLayoutAlign="center">
    menu
</md-icon>

<md-menu #dataActions="mdMenu">
    <button md-menu-item (click)="doEdit()" *ngIf="!isLocked()">
        <md-icon>edit</md-icon>
        <span>Edit</span>
    </button>
    <button md-menu-item (click)="doSubmit()" *ngIf="isEdit()">
        <md-icon>done</md-icon>
        <span>Submit</span>
    </button>
</md-menu>
```